# How can one extract an address balance at a specific height?

Tags: block, balance, height

Is it possible to view the balance of an address at a specific height, without using any external web api?

Could it perhaps be done using [bx](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer) or the [Bitcoin client API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)?

Comment: bx does use external API's.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively hard to achieve, because if you wish to allow querying any address at any height you deal with a **LOT** of data. You probably would need serve database server (cluster).

I'm pretty sure, getting a balance at a specific height from a specific address is not possible over a existing app or API.

You could try built it yourself with bitcoin-core as basis.
Maybe have a look at the >1year old [address index patch](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/3652) from Johnathan Corgan. But it would required additional to allow a API where you could define the height.

But caching every address at every possible height (Juli 29 2015: 367456, amount of addresses ~250k) is nearly impossible.